# cannot invoke a HTTP delete method not deleting RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am following a tutorial and I am trying to invoke a delete method like this:

in users/index.html.erb I got:

```
<!-- View for index action in user's controleer -->
<h1>All users - Administration Page</h1>

<%= will_paginate %>

<ul class="users">
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to user.name, user %>
      <!-- if the current user is admin -->
        <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
            | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete, confirm: "You sure?" %>
        <% end %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

in my users controller I got this:

```
  #destroying users!
  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
    redirect_to users_path
  end
```

instead of getting a confirm box, I am being redirected into the user's profile?!
It seems that rails server cannot read the delete method I am sending to it!

Edit:
rake routes:

```
rake routes
intergration_test_authentication_pages GET    /intergration_test/authentication_pages(.:format) intergration_test#authentication_pages
                                  root        /                                                 static_pages#home
                          user_profile        /user_profile(.:format)                           users#show_user
                            all_videos        /all_videos(.:format)                             static_pages#allvideos
                        show_interface        /show_interface(.:format)                         static_pages#interface
                                 users GET    /users(.:format)                                  users#index
                                       POST   /users(.:format)                                  users#create
                              new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                              users#new
                             edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                         users#edit
                                  user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                              users#show
                                       PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                              users#update
                                       DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                              users#destroy
                              sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)                               sessions#create
                           new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)                           sessions#new
                               session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)                           sessions#destroy
                                signup        /signup(.:format)                                 users#new
                                signin        /signin(.:format)                                 sessions#new
                               signout        /signout(.:format)                                sessions#destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

More than likely you are not including the necessary [jQuery UJS](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) Javascript on your page.  This is what allows the `:method` parameter to work properly.

Answer (score -1):

I saw a few problems in the syntax on your link_to. Try updating this part:
:method => :delete, :confirm => "You sure?"

Comment: He's using the new Ruby 1.9 syntax, meaning his syntax with regards to that is fine.